# Python ordering the list according to another list

Tags: python

I want to order `myList` based on the another list(`myorderList`) which stores the order of it. For example, myorderList=[3,1,2] indicates that the first element of `myList` is mapped to "two" because the smallest number is 1 in `myorderList` and then "one" and final element mapped to "zero" according to order of `myorderList`.

I have done this it works but i feel that it is not a good method to map the order of `myList`. I am looking for a better way to do that.

```
    myorderList=[]
    myneworderedList=[]
    myList=["zero","two","one"]
    myorderList=[3,1,2]
    for i in range(len(myList)):# just to eliminate index out of range error
        myneworderedList.append(i)

    for index,item in enumerate(myorderList):
        myneworderedList[int(item)-1]=myList[index]
    print myneworderedList
```

The result:

```
['two', 'one', 'zero']
```

Comment: Is the list `myorderList` always a list of consecutive indices, or could it also be something like `[13, 7, 42]`?

Comment: Not necessarily, it could be a list that you said.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option is to zip the two lists together, sort, and extract only the bits you are interetsed in from the result:

```
>>> [y for x, y in sorted(zip(myorderList, myList))]
['two', 'one', 'zero']
```

Another option is to use a custom key function that returns the order keys in the correct order:

```
>>> it = iter(myorderList)
>>> sorted(myList, key=lambda x: next(it))
['two', 'one', 'zero']
```

Python gurantees that the key function is called once per item of the input list and in the right order.

More specifically, before starting to sort the input list, the `sorted()` implementation iterates over the list and calls the key function for each item.  The key function given above ignores its argument and simply returns the next item from `myorderList`, which results in the desired key being used for each element of `myList`.  After this, `sorted()` sorts the list according to the previously determined keys.

Comment: Can you explain whats happening in your second example?

Comment: Cool answer but I would always recommend the first option over the second. I think it's more readable at a glance.

Comment: @abc: I added a bit of explanation.